# How to connect to a specific Managed Server using WLST (and not the Admin Server)

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

When a wlst python script need to specificaly connect to a managed server for an operation the connect command always connect to the Admin servers :

```
/{INSTALL_PATH}/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh {MY_PY_SCRIPT}.py 

connect(username,password,t3://{MY_MANAGEDSERVER_IP_ADRESS}:{T3PORT})
#or connect(username,password,t3://{MY_MANAGEDSERVER_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:{T3PORT})

Connecting to t3://{MY_MANAGEDSERVER_IP_ADRESS}:51001 with userid weblogic ...
Successfully connected to Admin Server 'AdminServer' that belongs to domain 'Domain'.
```

How can we force the *connect* wlst command to connect to the managed server and not the Admin Server ?

Comment: Check that your IP address and port are really pointing to your managed server.

Comment: Made a mistake with the port, it was the admin port and not the managed ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of admin host and port in your connect, statement use managed host and port. It will work like charm.